# Trouble with matlab array indexing

Tags: python, matlab

I have a matlab array named data

`34.6237   78.0247         0
   30.2867   43.8950         0
   35.8474   72.9022         0
   60.1826   86.3086    1.0000
   79.0327   75.3444    1.0000
   45.0833   56.3164         0
   61.1067   96.5114    1.0000
   75.0247   46.5540    1.0000
   76.0988   87.4206    1.0000
   84.4328   43.5334    1.0000`

these are the three fields. Now i want to get the values into two variables say A and B but A should contain the values for which the third column has entries 1 and B should contain the values for which the third column has entries 0

So the sample Output for this case would be

`A = 
   60.1826   86.3086
   79.0327   75.3444
   61.1067   96.5114
   75.0247   46.5540
   76.0988   87.4206
   84.4328   43.5334`

Similarly the rest of the entries would be for B

`B = 
   34.6237   78.0247
   30.2867   43.8950
   35.8474   72.9022
   45.0833   56.3164`

I do not want to do this by writing loops and extracting them.
I tried
`tempVariable = data(y > 0)`

Where variable `y  = data(:, 3)`

Can someone suggest a one liner to do this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
maskA = data(:,3) == 1;
A = data( maskA, [1 2]);
B = data(~maskA, [1 2]);
```

What we are doing here is:

1. Creating a N-by-1 logical vector which is `true` for all of the `A` rows.
2. Defining `A` as all of the `maskA` rows, and columns [1 2]
3. Defining `B` as all of the NOT `maskA` rows, and columns [1 2]

Comment: Thanks for the answer your answer gave me a hint to solve this in one line but more or less i did the same